# Spring3 mybatis 3 mapper no such bean found exception

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I am trying Spring 3 + Mybatis3 + mysql but didn't work out, tried almost all of the tutorials getting same exception, may be some one here can help me out

Following is the Error trace output and i have also attached list down the source code please help me out

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.triage.persistance.UserService com.triage.persistance.UserServiceImpl.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.triage.persistance.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
        ... 39 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.triage.persistance.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
        ... 41 more
```

** User.java **

```
package com.triage.domain;

public class User {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String standard;
    private int age;
    private String sex;
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getStandard() {
        return standard;
    }
    public void setStandard(String standard) {
        this.standard = standard;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }
    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }
}
```

** UserService.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.triage.persistance.UserService">

    <resultMap id="userResult" type="user">
        <result property="id" column="id" />
        <result property="name" column="name" />
        <result property="standard" column="standard" />
        <result property="age" column="age" />
        <result property="sex" column="sex" />

    </resultMap>

    <select id="getAllUsers" resultMap="userResult">
        SELECT id, name, standard, age, sex FROM USER
    </select>
</mapper>
```

** sqlmap-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

<configuration>
    <settings>
        <!-- changes from the defaults -->
       <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="false" />
    </settings>
    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias type="com.triage.domain.User" alias="user"/>
    </typeAliases>
</configuration>
```

** UserService.java **

```
package com.triage.persistance;

import java.util.List;

import com.triage.domain.User;

public interface UserService {

    public List<User> getAllUsers();
}
```

** test-application context **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        ">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.triage" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/jdbc.properties" />


    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <!-- jdbc template -->
    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:sqlmap-config.xml" /> 
        <property name="mapperLocations"
            value="classpath:mappers/*.xml" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

** My test case  Execution point **

```
package com.triage.test;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;

import com.triage.domain.User;
import com.triage.persistance.UserService;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:test-applicationContext.xml")
@TestExecutionListeners(value = { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class })
public class HelloPortletTestContext extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService; ** Error no such bean found error
//
//  @Autowired
//  private SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory; // If i try this successfully found this object

    @Test
    public void testHelloAccount() {
        List<User> items = userService.getAllUsers();
        System.out.println(items.size());
        Assert.assertTrue(!items.isEmpty());
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following two configurations into your spring context file

use spring-mybatis version 1.2.0

Change: Change your sqlSession factory to read your mappers files

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis/sqlmap-config.xml" />
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:mybatis/mappers/*.xml" />
</bean>
```

Add following entry

```
<!-- scan for mappers and let them be autowired -->
    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.comcast.triage.persistance" />
    </bean>
```